# Retrieve the assembly code from a PE file section in C

Tags: c, security, code-injection, portable-executable

I'm trying to write a simple PE file injector.
The basic idea is that I open and map both (payload and target) files. Then extract the .text section from the payload, find a codecave in the target and copy the "shellcode" into the codecave.

I'm having trouble with extracting the "shellcode" from the payload, or at least this is what i think it's the problem.

This is the full code of the program: https://pastebin.com/LGBw3DkD

But, the important code to this specific question is this:

```
// Retrieve shellcode size and pointer to the code
shellcodeSize = GetShellcodeSize(lpPayBase, &offsetShellcode);

...some other code...

// Create buffer for payload
hHeap  = HeapCreate(0, 0, shellcodeSize);
lpHeap = HeapAlloc(hHeap, HEAP_ZERO_MEMORY, shellcodeSize);

// Load the payload in the buffer
memcpy(lpHeap, lpPayBase + offsetShellcode, shellcodeSize);

// Copy the payload in codecave
memcpy((LPBYTE)(lpTgBase + injPos), lpHeap, shellcodeSize);
```

The **GetShellcodeSize()** function's code:

```
int GetShellcodeSize(LPBYTE lpFileBase, DWORD *shellcodeOff) {
   PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER pDosH = RetrieveDosH(lpFileBase);

   // Find .text section
   PIMAGE_SECTION_HEADER txtSection = FindSection(".text", pDosH);
   if (txtSection == NULL) {
       return 0;
   }
   else {
       // Retrieve offset to the code
       *shellcodeOff = txtSection->PointerToRawData;

       // Return the size
       return txtSection->SizeOfRawData;
  }
}
```

The problem is that when I add the shellcode's offset to the mapped file, I get this:
[Screenshot layout of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEcnF.png)

So, when i copy the shellcode into the memory and after into the codecave, it is copying from address 0x000E0400 --> 0x000E0417 (excepting the null bytes)
My question is:

1. If this is the actual code of the .text section (shellcode) why the infected program is not executing it?
2. Maybe this is the wrong way to do it?
3. Maybe the way I do it is the right way, but i mess up on changing the entry point?

**NOTE:** *The shellcode is written in assembly (32bit) and it's just calling MessageBox from the windows API. Also the C program is written as a 32bit app.*

Any help will be very appreciated, I struggle with this for some time and after all, I just want to understand the PE file format better. So any resources will be welcome.

Please check the full code if you have the time to do so.

If this is the wrong place to ask such a question please redirect me to the right place.
Thank you, and have a nice day!

Comment: *Create buffer for payload..// Load the payload in the buffer* - can you explain sense of this ?

Comment: I'm actually allocating memory in the heap and then copying the .text section code, retrieved earlier by the GetShellcodeSize function , into that allocated memory into the heap. After I'm just copying the shellcode(which is in the heap now) into the codecave, by adding the offset (of the codecave) to the mapped target file. I should actually replace that with //Allocating memory into the heap for shellcode, //Copy the shellcode to the heap allocated memory.

Comment: for what you allocating memory in the heap and then copying the .text section. why not just  copying the .text section

Comment: I want to be able to resume the normal code execution of the program, but for now I'm not even able to execute the shellcode, so it's in there for future reference. (The shellcode will have an instruction like [jmp placeholder], and i need to replace that placeholder with the original entry point to resume code execution)

Comment: but i ask you about sense of senseless code

Comment: Well, from my point of view i think it's not senseless code and it gives you more context about my question and the code I used, also it's better to have more information related to your question than less. At least that's how I think. :D